# Conver string to integer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting a numeric value from an element using

```
$('.myEm').text();
```

It returns a number from the element, but I need to increment the value by another value.How do I convert it to an integer?

Comment: `+$('.myEm').text();`?

Comment: that converts to a Number, not an integer (if that matters). you can do ~~"123.456"

Answer (score 0):

Use parseInt(... ) mate.

```
var a = parseInt("10")
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp